# Ajax only works with an even number of posts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

When I click the "download more" button, 3 entries are added to the existing posts on the page, but they are repeated and show the same ones that already exist or it only works if an even number (% 2) of posts. I want to add new three posts every time

custom template. Now see 3 posts.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'paged' => 1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    <div class="blog-posts1">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Show</a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>     
<?php endif; ?>
```

Function, whict, when i click button "load more" add posts.

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
 check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
$paged = $_POST['page'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        <div class="blog-posts1">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Show</a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>     
    <?php endif; wp_die(); ?>
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax1', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback1');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax1', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback1');
```

My ajax

```
var ajaxurl = "";
  var publication = 1;
  jQuery(function($) {
   function appendPost(data, callback) {
   $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if ($.trim(response) == '') {
      $('.loadmore').hide();
    }
   $('.blog-posts').append(response);
   publication++;
   data.page = publication;
   $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if ($.trim(response) == '') {
      $('.loadmore').hide();
   }
  });
 });
}

$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
   var data = {
    'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
    'page': publication,
    'security': blog.security
   };
  appendPost(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you seeing the correct value in `$paged = $_POST['page'];`? Also, this isn't the bug, but do you need `wp_die()` in `load_posts_by_ajax_callback`? There's a div tag there that looks like it can be removed.

Comment: I delete this `div` in this question. In this question is not ALL MAKRUP, because it's very very long.

Comment: In the `$args` array you set `'paged'`. Isn't it `'page'`?

Comment: @Moutah with `paged` it's works like that,  just repeats all the entries .But with `page` repeats the last record 1001 times

Comment: Is the `$paged = $_POST['page'];` value that is in `load_posts_by_ajax_callback` what you expect to see? Is it incrementing correctly?

Comment: @Spudly  Well, first it shows 2, and then it increases by 1. And the same thing can only be loaded in a different sequence and so on and again ...

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic The problem sounds like a pagination issue, but if those values are correct then I'm not sure why it would return the same posts.

Comment: @Spudly  Yes, I also can not find the problem